# Backbone View extend strange behavior

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I've been playing with backbone view a bit lately and I just encountered a VERY strange  behavior when creating my own view subclasses :

It seems to me that calling extend() on subclasses of Backbone.View tries to merge object attributes in the superclass definition (sorry for the barbaric phrasing) .

Please consider the following code :

```
(function() {
var SomeCustomView = Backbone.View.extend({
    children : {},

    //internal use only
    _children : {},

    counter : 0,

    initialize : function(options){
    },

    render : function(){
        var t = this;
        _.each(this.children, function(child, childId){
            if(_.isFunction(child))child=child.call(this);
            this._children[childId] = child;
            this.counter++;
        },t );

        return this;
    },

});

//register on window object
this.SomeCustomView = SomeCustomView;


}).call(this);
```

then creating subclasses of SomeCustomView  :

```
(function() {

console.error("START STRANGE BUG TEST");

var BetterCustomView = SomeCustomView.extend({
    children : {
        firstChild : { name : 'hi'}
    }
});

var instance1 = new BetterCustomView({ id : 'one' });

console.error("   _____________________________   ");

console.error("instance1.counter before render" + instance1.counter);
instance1.render();
console.error("instance1.counter after render" + instance1.counter);

console.error("instance1 _children");
console.error(instance1._children);

console.error("instance1._children.firstChild");
console.error(instance1._children.firstChild);
console.error("instance1._children.secondChild");
console.error(instance1._children.secondChild);

console.error("   _____________________________   ");



var EvenBetterCustomView = SomeCustomView.extend({
    children : {
        firstChild : { name : 'wuazza', foo : 'bar' },
        secondChild : { name : 'NotSupposedToBeInUltimate'}
    }
});

var instance2 = new EvenBetterCustomView({ id : 'two' });

console.error("   _____________________________   ");

console.error("instance2.counter before render" + instance2.counter);
instance2.render();
console.error("instance2.counter after render" + instance2.counter);

console.error("instance2 _children");
console.error(instance2._children);

console.error("instance2._children.firstChild");
console.error(instance2._children.firstChild);
console.error("instance2._children.secondChild");
console.error(instance2._children.secondChild);

console.error("   _____________________________   ");




var TheUltimateCustomView = SomeCustomView.extend({
    children : {
        firstChild : { name : 'whizzz' }
    }
});

var instance3 = new TheUltimateCustomView({ id : 'three' });

console.error("   _____________________________   ");

console.error("instance3.counter before render" + instance3.counter);
instance3.render();
console.error("instance3.counter after render" + instance3.counter);

console.error("instance3 _children");
console.error(instance3._children);

console.error("instance3._children.firstChild");
console.error(instance3._children.firstChild);
console.error("instance3._children.secondChild");
console.error(instance3._children.secondChild);


console.error("   _____________________________   ");

 }).call(this);
```

now the console outputs the following :

```
        START STRANGE BUG TEST test.html:46
       _____________________________    test.html:56
    instance1.counter before render0 test.html:58
    instance1.counter after render1 test.html:60
    instance1 _children test.html:62
    Object {firstChild: Object}
     test.html:63
    instance1._children.firstChild test.html:65
    Object {name: "hi"} test.html:66
    instance1._children.secondChild test.html:67
    undefined test.html:68
       _____________________________    test.html:70
       _____________________________    test.html:83
    instance2.counter before render0 test.html:85
    instance2.counter after render2 test.html:87
    instance2 _children test.html:89
    Object {firstChild: Object, secondChild: Object}
     test.html:90
    instance2._children.firstChild test.html:92
    Object {name: "wuazza", foo: "bar"} test.html:93
    instance2._children.secondChild test.html:94
    Object {name: "NotSupposedToBeInUltimate"} test.html:95
       _____________________________    test.html:97
       _____________________________    test.html:110
    instance3.counter before render0 test.html:112
    instance3.counter after render1 test.html:114
    instance3 _children test.html:116
    Object {firstChild: Object, secondChild: Object}
     test.html:117
    instance3._children.firstChild test.html:119
    Object {name: "whizzz"} test.html:120
    instance3._children.secondChild test.html:121
    Object {name: "NotSupposedToBeInUltimate"} test.html:122
       _____________________________
```

Notice that each time in the actual tests I extend SomeCustomView.
Notice how in the third subclass TheUltimateCustomView you can find the 'secondChild' that was declared inside EvenBetterCustomView and placed inside the _children object during the call to render() ;

To me this is a very odd behavior to say the least.

TheUltimateCustomView does not extend EvenBetterCustomView in which secondChild was declared. Moreover, we are testing the _children object which is populated during a call to render() on an SUBCLASS's INSTANCE of our CustomViewClass. 
How does it end up in other subclasses CustomViewClass ... ?

Can someone explain this to me ? 
Is this a bug in how BackBone.View performs its .extend method ?

Is it me doing something terribly wrong ?

```
            <html>

        <head>



            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var SomeCustomView = Backbone.View.extend({
                children : {},

                //internal use only
                _children : {},

                counter : 0,

                initialize : function(options){
                },

                render : function(){
                    var t = this;
                    _.each(this.children, function(child, childId){
                        if(_.isFunction(child))child=child.call(this);
                        this._children[childId] = child;
                        this.counter++;
                    },t );

                    return this;
                },

            });

            //register on window object
            this.SomeCustomView = SomeCustomView;


        }).call(this);


        (function() {

            console.error("START STRANGE BUG TEST");

            var BetterCustomView = SomeCustomView.extend({
                children : {
                    firstChild : { name : 'hi'}
                }
            });

            var instance1 = new BetterCustomView({ id : 'one' });

            console.error("   _____________________________   ");

            console.error("instance1.counter before render" + instance1.counter);
            instance1.render();
            console.error("instance1.counter after render" + instance1.counter);

            console.error("instance1 _children");
            console.error(instance1._children);

            console.error("instance1._children.firstChild");
            console.error(instance1._children.firstChild);
            console.error("instance1._children.secondChild");
            console.error(instance1._children.secondChild);

            console.error("   _____________________________   ");



            var EvenBetterCustomView = SomeCustomView.extend({
                children : {
                    firstChild : { name : 'wuazza', foo : 'bar' },
                    secondChild : { name : 'NotSupposedToBeInUltimate'}
                }
            });

            var instance2 = new EvenBetterCustomView({ id : 'two' });

            console.error("   _____________________________   ");

            console.error("instance2.counter before render" + instance2.counter);
            instance2.render();
            console.error("instance2.counter after render" + instance2.counter);

            console.error("instance2 _children");
            console.error(instance2._children);

            console.error("instance2._children.firstChild");
            console.error(instance2._children.firstChild);
            console.error("instance2._children.secondChild");
            console.error(instance2._children.secondChild);

            console.error("   _____________________________   ");




            var TheUltimateCustomView = SomeCustomView.extend({
                children : {
                    firstChild : { name : 'whizzz' }
                }
            });

            var instance3 = new TheUltimateCustomView({ id : 'three' });

            console.error("   _____________________________   ");

            console.error("instance3.counter before render" + instance3.counter);
            instance3.render();
            console.error("instance3.counter after render" + instance3.counter);

            console.error("instance3 _children");
            console.error(instance3._children);

            console.error("instance3._children.firstChild");
            console.error(instance3._children.firstChild);
            console.error("instance3._children.secondChild");
            console.error(instance3._children.secondChild);


            console.error("   _____________________________   ");

        }).call(this);

            </script>



        </head>


        <body>
        coucou

        </body>



        </html>
```

Below is the full html page in which you can test this behavior :

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more precise, when you do like this :

```
(function() {
var SomeCustomView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    //internal use only
    _children : {},

    ...

});
```

every instance has it's own `_children` field, but they all share the same initialized value `{}`, so all the views that will extend `SomeCustomView` will share the same value unless you change `_children` to another value.

Try something like this :

```
(function() {
var SomeCustomView = Backbone.View.extend({
    children : {},

    //internal use only
    _children : null, // or whatever you want

    ...

    render : function(){
        this._children = {}; // here your instance will have it's own value
        ...
    },

});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6myFQ/2/)

Comment: OK but how come the counter's value is 0 on each instance before render ? Also would there be another way to define _views in a superclass without having to redefine it each time in the subclasses ?  This seems very illogical to me otherwise, as I would expect extend to actually 'extend' the View class with a non-static object i.e. that is not shared with all other instances.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The difference between `_children` and `counter` is that the first is an object and the second is a primitive. The objects are assigned by reference while primitives are assigned by value.

Comment: Ok thank you Rida. I came accross this article which explains the problem in a lot of details and offers a good solution : 
http://www.erichynds.com/blog/backbone-and-inheritance